# specific Row in uiTableView behind navigation bar objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, storyboard

I want to have a fixed specific row in a tabaleview behind of navigation bar  or fixed specific row before first section in a uitableView and adding 3 images or buttons there like a below picture:

Fixed : I mean I don't want to scroll it!

I using storyboard and everything is programmatically.

Would You please help me ! I don't know how should I create this row.

Thanks In advance!

Comment: The answer of this question will help you.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825073/uiview-at-top-of-uitableview-in-uitableviewcontroller-without-scroll>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view at the top needs to be a separate view, so I would suggest building a UIViewController with a UIView at the top (the static bit) then a UiTableView below it. This will give you the effect you want.