# UIView at top of UITableView in UITableViewController without scroll

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I added uiView above uiTableViewController,

inside of my table I have some data with scroll but I don't want to have scroll for this uiview above my table

does anyone knows what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `UITableViewController`.  Use a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` and your additional `UIView` at the top.  A TableView Controller expects its view to be the only one.  Using a View Controller with a TableView gives you much more flexibility (A `UISearchBar` that is always visible is one of them too)